# How to pass php variable values into javascript var variables without onClick function?

Tags: javascript, php, google-maps-api-3

I have a coordinate(latlng) in a php variable. I need to pass these variables to the javascript google maps api request. I want to pass $lat1 and $lon1 to point1 in javascript without onClick function. How can I achieve this ?

```
    <?php
    $lat1 = 6.893732;
    $lon1 = 79.857516;
    $lat2 = 6.856007;
    $lon2 = 79.865284;
    ?>


    <html>
       <script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=YOUR_API_KEY&callback=initMap"
        async defer></script>
        <script>
            var point1 = {lat: 41.85, lng: -87.65}; //Send $point1 value here
            var point2 = {lat: 39.79, lng: -86.14}; //Send $point2 value here

            // Set destination, origin and travel mode.
          var request = {
          destination: point1,
          origin: point2,
          travelMode: 'DRIVING'
        };

        // Pass the directions request to the directions service.
        var directionsService = new google.maps.DirectionsService();
        directionsService.route(request, function(response, status) {
          if (status == 'OK') {
            // Display the route on the map.
            directionsDisplay.setDirections(response);
          }
        });

</script>
```

Comment: You can echo it as js variable: echo "<script>var lat1 = ".$lat1.";</script>";

Comment: Are the php and js code in the same file in your project? or in separate files?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just print it in your javascript code with php like below:

```
<?php
$lat1 = 6.893732;
$lon1 = 79.857516;
$lat2 = 6.856007;
$lon2 = 79.865284;
?>


<html>
   <script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=YOUR_API_KEY&callback=initMap"
    async defer></script>
    <script>
        var point1 = {lat: <?php echo $lat1 ?>, lng: <?php echo $lon1 ?>}; //Send $point1 value here
        var point2 = {lat: <?php echo $lat2 ?>, lng: <?php echo $lon2 ?>}; //Send $point2 value here

        // Set destination, origin and travel mode.
      var request = {
      destination: point1,
      origin: point2,
      travelMode: 'DRIVING'
    };

    // Pass the directions request to the directions service.
    var directionsService = new google.maps.DirectionsService();
    directionsService.route(request, function(response, status) {
      if (status == 'OK') {
        // Display the route on the map.
        directionsDisplay.setDirections(response);
      }
    });
```

Answer (score 2):

You can just echo the data into the JS variables like this...

```
var point1 = {lat: <?php echo $lat1 ?>, lng: <?php echo $lon1 ?>}; 
var point2 = {lat: <?php echo $lat2 ?>, lng: <?php echo $lon2 ?>};
```